# Skipping duplicate values of XML by XSL (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to create a string based on the repetitive nodes, and I need to skip duplicate values.

Input File:

```
<items>
<item>
    <code>
        <str>MN</str>
    </code>
</item>
<item>
    <code>
        <str>PT</str>
    </code>
</item>
<item>
    <code>
        <str>MN</str>
    </code>
</item>
<item>
    <code>
        <str>TS</str>
    </code>
</item>
<item>
    <code>
        <str>MP</str>
    </code>
</item>
<item>
    <code>
        <str>MN</str>
    </code>
</item>
 <item>
    <code>
        <str>TS</str>
    </code>
</item>
</items>
```

Required Output:

```
<items>MN#PT#TS#MP</items>
```

Here, I am required to remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key to look up `item` elements by their code string. This is a [well-known method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) that is also used as a grouping technique.

Your input XML is not well-formed, because the `items` element is not properly closed.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="item-by-code-str" match="item" use="code/str"/>

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id() =
                                  generate-id(key('item-by-code-str', code/str)[1])]">
              <xsl:value-of select="code/str"/>
              <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>MN#PT#TS#MP</items>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias Müller for quick reply.    Is there any performance issue when number of item more then 2 lac.

Comment: @DVekaria No, keys are a very efficient way to find elements. I have no idea what "2 lac" means I'm afraid.

Comment: 2 lac means 200000. I have checked and its working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @DVekaria Interesting, I've learned something today, too. You are welcome.